# Get the value of incremented input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, input

I have two buttons which either increment or decrement an input value. I don't know how to retrieve the value later on submit of the result. My current attempts have either resulted in 'undefined' or '0'.

Thanks in advance for any advice

```
$('.plus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});


$(".minus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});


//attempting to get value
var value = document.getElementById( 'inputval' ).val();


$('#submitscore').click(function() {
    alert(value);
});
```

My HTML

```
 <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-success minus" field='minusfield' id ="minus" type="button">-</button>
 </span>
 <input type="text" name="inputval" id="inputval" value="0" class="gh form-control" />
 <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-success plus" id="plus" field='plusfield' type="button">+</button>
 </span>
 <button type="button" id="submitscore" class="btn btn-md btn-orange">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to get already assigned value.

Change your code to this

```
$('#submitscore').click(function() {
        alert($('#inputval').val());
    });
```

and it should work.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I tried your code but am getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).val is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (score.js:179)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle

Comment: Sorry, my bad. val() is a jQuery specific function. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing standard Javascript usage with jQuery usage when you try to call it like this:

> ```
> //attempting to get value
> var value = document.getElementById( 'inputval' ).val();
> ```

Use one or the other:

**Standard Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById('inputval').value
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#inputval').val()
```